# Dynamically return entity attribute

Tags: outsystems

**Context**
Using Outsystems 11. I have an external REST API that is being consumed by my application, and a corresponding database table on SQL Server that matches the expected data type coming in from the API fields. However, I need to truncate some of the data from the API since it is exceeding spec.

**Question**
Is there a way to dynamically read an entity's length attribute so that I don't have to hard code length into the app?

**What I've tried**
Text LENGTH function

Example:

```
ArticleOut.Title = Substr(ArticleIn.Title,0,Length(ArticleOut.Title))
ArticleOut.Description = Substr(ArticleIn.Description,0,Length(ArticleOut.Description))
```

The Length function call is returning a length of 0 since there is no data in the field yet - and I hoped for it to return the entity attribute length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the table and attribute using entities `Entity` and `Entity_Attr` from `(System)` component.

`Entity_Attr` entity has one filed *Length* that should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi Filipe. Thank you. I'm struggling on how to find the entity ID to pass to Entity_Attr, and the Outsystems forums aren't much help.  Do you have an example of how I can retrieve the entity attributes by name? (I looked and searching for the Entity first to get the ID, but that also requires an ID....)

Comment: Via an aggregate, you can Join Entity with Entity_Attr by Entity.Id. The add a filter Entity.Name = "<MYENTITY>". You should now get all the attributes of your entity. Just go to the attribute you're looking for (by name) and the length of it is on Entity_Attr:Length attribute.